# Testing a Maven submodule

Tags: maven, testing

I'm working on a html2pdf ([GitHub project](https://github.com/itext/i7j-pdfhtml)) customization. So I've downloaded the source code and I've imported it into the Eclipse Oxygen. I'm trying to execute the tests of this project, but every maven goal I run has no effect on the project. Yet, I've tried to execute the command explained here ([To run tests](https://github.com/itext/i7j-pdfhtml/blob/develop/BUILDING.md)), but nothing has happened.

So, my newbie question is: How can I run the tests of this project?

Here is the `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>root</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath />
  </parent>

  <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>pdfHTML</name>
  <description>pdfHTML is an iText 7 add-on that lets you to parse (X)HTML snippets and the associated CSS and converts
    them to PDF.</description>
  <url>http://itextpdf.com/</url>

  <properties>
    <itext.version>${project.parent.version}</itext.version>
    <javadoc.version>3.0.0</javadoc.version>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>itext-snapshot</id>
      <name>iText Repository - snapshots</name>
      <url>https://repo.itextsupport.com/snapshot</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>itext-releases</id>
      <name>iText Repository - releases</name>
      <url>https://repo.itextsupport.com/releases</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
      <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
      <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
      <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
      <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
      <artifactId>hyph</artifactId>
      <version>${itext.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
      <artifactId>pdfa</artifactId>
      <version>${itext.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
      <artifactId>pdftest</artifactId>
      <version>${itext.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.properties</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.css</include>
          <include>**/*.ttf</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>external.atlassian.jgitflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>jgitflow-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-m5.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
          </includes>
          <groups>${integrationtests}</groups>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${javadoc.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <quiet>true</quiet>
          <failOnError>true</failOnError>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <groups>${unittests}</groups>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
        <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.11</version>
        <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.revapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>revapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

And, an excerpt of the parent module configuration is:

```
<properties>
    <unittests>com.itextpdf.test.annotations.type.UnitTest</unittests>
</properties>
...
<!-- Run unit tests -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${surefire.version}</version>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
      <skipTests>false</skipTests>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
      </includes>
      <groups>${unittests}</groups>
      <forkCount>1</forkCount>
      <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
      <threadCount>10</threadCount>
      <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: What is the output when you run `mvn clean install` as described?

Comment: There is no any output! It seems that nothing is running on executing maven goals.

Comment: An addition information: every test class is annotated with `@Category`

Comment: Do you run Maven from a console? If so, please verify that Maven is correctly installed by running `mvn --version`

Comment: I've added a snippet of the `pom.xml` of the parent module to my post. After running `mvn --version` the output I've got is: 
`Maven home: C:\Maven\bin\..`
`Java version: 1.8.0_161, vendor: Oracle Corporation`
`Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161`
`Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252`
`OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"`

Comment: I'm running Maven from Eclipse.

Comment: The output looks okay. What happens when you run `mvn clean install` from a console?

Comment: Very nice, man! Now, so many things have been shown in the output. But, why are such commands not working from Eclipse?